# Aptana 3.0 JS Code Assist not working with namespace that begins with karma

Tags: javascript, dojo, aptana, code-assist

We are using Aptana 3.0 to develop our JS application. We are using the dojo toolkit. In the toolkit there is a utility to generate docs, called docscripts. It generates an xml file. We have been able to get Aptana to recognize the file, but something is odd. Our namespace which we are using, "karma", does not seem to "work". When we change the namespace to "foo" or any other string, even "karma2", the code assist works.

Is there something against "karma" being used as a namespace? All of the dojo, dijit, and dojox classes are provided thru code assist as expected.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly nothing directly blocking that name. If you can file a bug with the XML file you are using, that would be great.